# Android - Glide resizing image via "override" and "fitCenter" deforms Bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-glide

I'm using Glide to load images from gallery into `GLSurfaceView`. However, when I tried to resize the image using `override(width, height)`, it does not do so. Thus, I added `fitCenter()`, which seems to be the key to get the desired size.

My problem is when the `Bitmap` is resized the result is quite weird! Everything is good except for images that have small width values. The attached pictures illustrate the difference between using and not using `fitCenter()`.

Here's the code I used for loading via Glide

```
Glide.with(this)
    .load(imageUri)
    .asBitmap()
    .override(newWidth, newHeight)
    .fitCenter()
    .atMost()
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(newWidth, newHeight) {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Loaded Bitmap Size :" + resource.getWidth() + "x" + resource.getHeight());
            /*
            .
            . Initialize GLSurfaceView with Bitmap resource
            .
            */
        }
    }) ;
```

I thought for a second that it may be a `GLSurfaceView` problem, something related to very small width I guessed. But it looks that it renders perfectly until the image is resized.

Is there anything wrong with my code? I would really appreciate any suggestion.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem occurs when using `fitCenter()` with `GLSurfaceView` with a `Bitmap` that has either width or height as an odd number. I solved the issue by adding the following custom transformation to `Glide` call.

```
@Override
protected Bitmap transform(BitmapPool pool, Bitmap toTransform, int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
    if (maxHeight > 0 && maxWidth > 0) {
        int width = toTransform.getWidth();
        int height = toTransform.getHeight();

        float ratioBitmap = (float) width / (float) height;
        float ratioMax = (float) maxWidth / (float) maxHeight;

        int finalWidth = maxWidth;
        int finalHeight = maxHeight;
        if (ratioMax > ratioBitmap) {
            finalWidth = (int) ((float) maxHeight * ratioBitmap);
        } else {
            finalHeight = (int) ((float)maxWidth / ratioBitmap);
        }

        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(toTransform, previousEvenNumber(finalWidth), previousEvenNumber(finalHeight), true);
    }
    else {
        return toTransform;
    }
}

private int previousEvenNumber(int x){
    if ( (x & 1) == 0 )
        return x;
    else
        return x - 1;
}
```

And editing `Glide` call to the following:

```
Glide.with(this)
    .load(imageUri)
    .asBitmap()
    .override(newWidth, newHeight)
    .transform(new CustomFitCenter(this))
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Loaded Bitmap Size :" + resource.getWidth() + "x" + resource.getHeight());
            /*
            .
            . Initialize GLSurfaceView with Bitmap resource
            .
            */
        }
    }) ;
```

I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it, but it worked.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39187451/3) to the question [Android - Glide resizing image via "override" and "fitCenter" deforms Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187451/android-glide-resizing-image-via-override-and-fitcenter-deforms-bitmap) by the OP [Zac Jokface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4438088/zac-jokface) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>